# Preapproval key in Android

Tags: android, paypal-subscriptions

How can i obtain PreApproval key for PayPal subscription? How the Preapprovals are working in Android?

Comment: Upvote..i m also stuck in same condition.Can anyone have some idea how generate Preapproval key?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a cached blog post [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aNSoZDbwtPrMJ%3amobworld.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/preapproval-process-using-paypal-mpl-in-android/%20PreApproval%20android&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk), which outlines the steps one needs to take in order to obtain a PayPal PreApproval key.

Comment: Tried it : it doesn't work. There is definitely a problem with the documentation because there are no samples showing how the process works. It is a little bit frustrating ...please upvote so that we can (all) move forward

Comment: Here is a link : https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/creating-ebook-store-android-part-3 that may help you. Actually, I have managed to get the preapp key from the server but when I use it in the PaypalPreapproval object (in android) then it just doesn't work : it says **Invalid request paramater : preapprovalKey with value XXXXX**. I just don't understand since it's the newly created key that I received from an HTTP post sent to the server ...